# How to use the POSIX package of Guile 2.2?

Tags: linux, guile

### Context:

I am currently coding the [generate-ninja-build.scm](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/generate-ninja-build.scm) script in [`git commit` cb7530e3ff10](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/commit/cb7530e3ff10c9ecab20125b5036fafa77f8d3f1) of my GPLv3+ project [bismon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_readiness_level) (funded by [H2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_Programmes_for_Research_and_Technological_Development#Horizon_2020) research projects). This is contractually some Linux free software project supposed to run on Debian.

That script should become an improvement over the existing shell script  [bismon/generate-ninja-builder.sh](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/blob/master/generate-ninja-builder.sh) which generates some `build.ninja` file for the [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) tool (some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) one).

#### Question:

The current `generate-ninja-build.scm`  has just (outside of copyright notice comment) :

```
 (use-modules
  ;; see https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Modules.html
   (ice-9 posix)  ;;;; problematic line, but why ?
   (ice-9 readline)
   (ice-9 format)
   (ice-9 pretty-print)
   )

 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; constants
 (define bm-packages '("glib-2.0" "jansson" "gtk+-3.0"))
 (define bm-gcc "gcc")
```

but when I run it as `./generate-ninja-build.scm` on my Debian/Sid, whose `guile --version` gives

```
guile (GNU Guile) 2.2.4
Packaged by Debian (2.2.4-deb+1-3)
```

I am getting:

```
rimski.x86_64 ~/bismon 8:17 .0 % ./generate-ninja-build.scm 
;;; note: auto-compilation is enabled, set GUILE_AUTO_COMPILE=0
;;;       or pass the --no-auto-compile argument to disable.
;;; compiling /home/basile/bismon/./generate-ninja-build.scm
;;; WARNING: compilation of /home/basile/bismon/generate-ninja-build.scm failed:
;;; no code for module (ice-9 posix)
Backtrace:
           9 (primitive-load "/home/basile/bismon/./generate-ninja-b…")
In ice-9/eval.scm:
   721:20  8 (primitive-eval (use-modules (ice-9 posix) (ice-9 #) # …))
In ice-9/psyntax.scm:
  1235:36  7 (expand-top-sequence ((use-modules (ice-9 posix) (…) …)) …)
  1182:24  6 (parse _ (("placeholder" placeholder)) ((top) #(# # …)) …)
   285:10  5 (parse _ (("placeholder" placeholder)) (()) _ c&e (eval) …)
In ice-9/boot-9.scm:
  3377:20  4 (process-use-modules _)
   222:17  3 (map1 (((ice-9 posix)) ((ice-9 readline)) ((ice-9 #)) #))
  3378:31  2 (_ ((ice-9 posix)))
   2803:6  1 (resolve-interface _ #:select _ #:hide _ #:prefix _ # _ …)
In unknown file:
           0 (scm-error misc-error #f "~A ~S" ("no code for modu…" …) …)

ERROR: In procedure scm-error:
no code for module (ice-9 posix)
```

however the output of `locate ice-9/posix` includes:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guile/2.0/ccache/ice-9/posix.go
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guile/2.2/ccache/ice-9/posix.go
/usr/share/guile/2.0/ice-9/posix.scm
/usr/share/guile/2.2/ice-9/posix.scm
```

So **I was expecting the `(ice-9 posix)` line to work.
 If I comment that line, everything works as I want.**

My `~/.guile` just has:

```
;; file ~/.guile
(use-modules 
  (ice-9 readline)
  (ice-9 format)
  (ice-9 pretty-print))

(activate-readline)
```

and [my interactive `guile` works like a charm](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/guile-tutorial-1.html) with the expected fancy GNU readline and autocompletion interface.

#### What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt install guile-2.2-dev guile-2.0-dev guile-1.8-dev

Consider use Guix instead Debian. All develop dependencies is install by default in replace of Python. http://guix.gnu.org/

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any mention of a `(ice-9 posix)` module in the guile 2.2 documentation, and while the appropriate file exists in the source tree, the `modules/ice-9` directory [README](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=guile.git;a=blob_plain;f=module/ice-9/README;hb=refs/heads/stable-2.2) says

> The non-module files are:
>
> boot-9.scm    -- loaded on guile startup
>
> ...
>
> posix.scm -- loaded by boot-9.scm

You can't load it because it's not a module file intended to be loaded by user code. Same thing applies at least as far back as guile 1.8, so if you found some documentation or tutorial somewhere including an attempt to load a module by that name, it's simply wrong.

Comment: Note that the README file is only available in the Git repository and it's a bit strange to talk about "non-module" file.